# Vuetify table (v 2.6.3)

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I am a beginner in Vue.js and Vuetify:

1. I have a Vuetify data table and I am trying to append different icons (customized icons from flaticon) to just the column for example "fat (g)". Means every new line has it's own icon.
2. Moreover I like to have a title instead of the checkmark in the v-table-header.

How can I do this in the following code?

Example code:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/v-data-table/prop-row-selection.vue:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :single-select="singleSelect"
      item-key="name"
      show-select
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-switch
          v-model="singleSelect"
          label="Single select"
          class="pa-3"
        ></v-switch>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
</template> 

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      singleSelect: false,
      selected: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this codesanbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70958304-brw8z?file=/src/components/AppendIcons.vue

[image: Table preview]

Well it depends, how do you want to decide what icon use for each row. The normal aproach would be to have the desired icon name within your data array.

```js
desserts: [
{
  name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
  calories: 159,
  fat: 6.0,
  carbs: 24,
  protein: 4.0,
  iron: '1%',
  icon: 'home'
},
...
]
```

Now to append the icon to the fat(g) column can be done using the `item` slot of your `v-data-table`. In my example I used the `#item.fat="{item}"` which is a shortand for `v-slot:item.fat="{item}"` to modify the content of the fat column. For more info about slots check the [documentation page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#slots).

If you're using es-lint you might encounter a warning mention something about the `valid-v-slot` rule, this is a known false positive that you can read more about in this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1165), I personally just turn that es-lint rule off.

```html
<v-data-table
   v-model="selected"
   :headers="headers"
   :items="desserts"
   item-key="name"
   show-select
   class="elevation-1"
>
   <template v-slot:top>
      <div class="my-2 mx-4 text-h5 font-weight-medium">
         My custom title
      </div>
   </template>
   <template #item.fat="{item}">
      <div class="d-flex">
         <div>
            {{ item.fat }}
         </div>
         <div class="ml-2">
            <i :class="`fi fi-rr-${item.icon}`"></i>
         </div>
      </div>
   </template>
</v-data-table>
```

### **UPDATE 1: Import flaticon through CDN.**

```css
<style>
/* <style> blocks that doesn't have the 'scoped' attribute
 make the CSS available in all your components, I usually put
 my global CSS in the App.vue file or in a external css file.
 
 In this case I'm just importing the regular rounded style
 of flaticons, if you want to use bold, solid, straight icons
 you'll need to import those as well */
@import url("https://cdn-uicons.flaticon.com/uicons-regular-rounded/css/uicons-regular-rounded.css");

i {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
</style>
```

Vuetify components use material icons by default inside of them, in case you want to go one step further and modify those icons to use flaticons. Instead of creating a wrapper component or manually defining the specific icon each time a component appears, you can configure it at a global level, see [Icons Font docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#using-custom-icons) for more info.

Let's say you want to modify the sort arrow icon used in vuetify components to use the arrow-small-up flaticon. Then you would do something like this:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    values: {
      sort: "fi fi-rr-arrow-small-up"
    },
  },
})
```

### **UPDATE 2: How to use custom SVG files in vuetify.**

Local SVG files can be displayed in your applicaction by simply using the normal `<img>` tag. Vuetify's `<v-img>` component can only display external SVG files that comes from an URL. Like this one right here: https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg

That's because the internal fileloader that use `<v-img>` doesn't support local SVG files. So the simplest solution is just use the normal `<img>` tag.

```html
<div>
   {{ item.fat }}
</div>
<div class="ml-2">
   <img v-if="item.name == 'Donut'" src="../assets/donut.svg" width="20" alt=""/>
   <i v-else :class="`fi fi-rr-${item.icon}`"></i>
</div>
```

[image: SVG Example]

Comment: Thank you very much. What if I want to have a customized icon from flaticon used in the rows?

Comment: Vuetify comes bootstrapped with support for Material Design Icons, Material Icons, Font Awesome 4 and Font Awesome 5. By default, applications will default to use Material Design Icons. If you want to have access to another icon library like flaticon, you'll need to import it following their instructions on their get started section.
https://www.flaticon.com/uicons/get-started

The way it will be implemented may vary depending on whether you want to download its library or import it to your project through its CDN.

Comment: I have updated the codesandbox to use flaticons that I import through the CDN. But if you want you can also download their files and put them in your assets folders and import  them from there.

Comment: Now I tried to also import selfmade icons (stored in src / assets / img as svg). For that I created an Component with the svg in it.

After I imported it in the vuetify.js with: 

Vue.component("my-icon", { template: `<svg height="24" width="24"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="9" fill="red"</svg>`});

const vuetifyOpts = { icons: { iconfont: "mdi", values: { myicon: { component: "my-icon"},} }; and returned in data():function(){ return{ myiconname: "$vuetify.icons.myicon",
But in your codepen it does not work.. any ideas how i can import selfmade svg in the table instead of flaticons?

Comment: There's no need to make a component for them, I remember seen some tutorials online that does that but, is as simple as show them with a  normal `<img>` tag. I've updated codesanbox to show a custom donut.svg icon in the "Donut" row. I'll also update my asnwer rn to explain more in detail about how to use local svg files with vuetify.

Comment: Thank you very much for updating your code sandbox, that helped a lot. Do you maybe know if I can style the table so that every row has a spacing to the other one (should look like the rows are independent from each other and from the header)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The way you're describing it to me, sounds more like how the [Data iterator component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-iterators/) works.